# Why are edits more important than comments?

Tags: discussion, edits, comments

As a new user on the site, I read through some of the pages and noticed that Stack Overflow only has three main features: "asking", "answering", and "editing".

However, why "editing"?

I would have thought something like commenting would be more valuable than edits. Is there a reason that edits are one of the main features of this site? If so, why?

Comment: If the main features are asking (questions) and answering (answers) then editing them is also important because you are making Questions/Answers better

Comment: @TemaniAfif But if you ask a question, you can't clarify what they mean with an edit, so wouldn't an comment be more useful?

Comment: edits aren't meant to change the author intent or to change the meaning but to make the question better (correct the english, make the code look cleaner, remove noises, etc)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**The primary purpose of comments is actually to facilitate edits**, with the ultimate goal of improving the quality and presentation of content on this site.

The placeholder text in the comment box says:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.

So, comments are intended to ask for clarification, suggest improvements, and/or add additional information to posts. All of these things should ultimately result in an edit to the post. Comments also be used to have a limited discussion about the post itself, but again, the culmination of this should ultimately be an edit to the post, incorporating what was discussed in the comments.

In this sense, **comments are an escape hatch. In a perfect world, every question would be completely clear and contain all the information needed to answer it. Every answer would be perfectly clear and complete. Alas, we don't live in a perfect world, so comments are an important way of compensating for that.**

But, intrinsically, comments have very little value. They are unwieldy, have poor visibility, and many people skip over them. Some people who come to Stack Overflow from traditional web forums like to use comments to have extended discussions, but this is a Q&A site. We do everything we can to *discourage* extended discussions. Reducing the emphasis on comments is part of this.

Why are edits so important? Well, for the same reason they're important on Wikipedia. This is a collaboratively-edited site collecting answers to programming questions. Edits are a major way that our content is enhanced, both in terms of its superficial presentation and also in terms of its technical information, and enhancing the site's content serves *everyone*, both current and future viewers.